# Concatenate XSLT values in 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have below XML

```
<Category>
<CD></CD>
<Books>
<Book Sold="Y">Program C</Book>
<Book Sold="Y" LessCost="Y">Maths-Yeshwant</Book>
<Book>Test</Book>
</Books>
</Category>
```

OutputExpected isfor above input:

Sold Books are ProgramC,Maths-Yeshwant,LessCost Books are Maths-Yeshwant

(if Sold attribute is not present then only second statement must be displayed LessCost Books are Maths-Yeshwant

if Less Cost is not present then only first statement must be displayed Sold Books are ProgramC

if both attributes are not present then the output must be empty)

Code i tried is below and is failing.This is written from book level

```
<xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">
    <xsl:variable name="SoldBooks" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="LessCostBooks" select="''"/>
    <xsl:text>Sold Books are</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@Sold='Y'">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat($SoldBooks,text(),',')">
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>Less Cost Books are</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@LessCost='Y'">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat($LessCostBooks,text(),',')">
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Can someone please let me know where i am going wrong as i am beginner.Also i need to do translation using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Perhaps before expecting answers to your 16th question, you might first accept some of the fine answers you've gotten to your previous 15 questions?  Surely more than 1 of those have been helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your input XML and in your XSLT.
Input XML: `<Category>` and `<Books>` are missing the corresponding closing tag, and `</Test>` should be `</Book>`.
XSLT: `<xsl:foreach select="Books/Book">` should be `<xsl:for-each select="Books/Book">`, and both `<xsl:when>` in the`<xsl:choose>` are missing the closing `</xsl:when>`.

For the corrected input XML

```
<Category>
  <CD></CD>
    <Books>
      <Book Sold="Y">Program C</Book>
      <Book Sold="Y" LessCost="Y">Maths-Yeshwant</Book>
      <Book>Test</Book>
    </Books>
</Category>
```

following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
   omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="Books">
     <xsl:if test="Book[@Sold='Y']">
       <xsl:text>Sold Books are </xsl:text>
       <xsl:for-each select="Book[@Sold='Y']">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!= last()">
          <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:if>

     <xsl:if test="Book[@LessCost='Y']">
       <xsl:if test="Book[@Sold='Y']">
         <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:text>Less Books are </xsl:text>
       <xsl:for-each select="Book[@LessCost='Y']">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="position()!= last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the output

```
Sold Books are Program C, Maths-Yeshwant, Less Books are Maths-Yeshwant
```

One misunderstanding in your XSLT is the approach to change a variable which is not possible in XSLT. For further information on variables in XSLT you can check e.g. http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N8090.html